# Marketing Cloud Connector Logs not generated

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm trying to find out why records are not getting injected in Journey Builder when using Salesforce Data Entry.

I've followed the documentation [right here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314336&type=1&mode=1) and the Debug logs are fine, the FireJBTrigger is triggered. So, I'm assuming the problem is somewhere at the SFMC Connect level.

I've initiated the logs from Marketing Cloud Connect's interface on Sales Cloud and tried to reproduce the problem, but can't find any files in Documents > Marketing Cloud Documents.

Do we have to specify the debug level somewhere so that the appropriate logs are generated?
How do you guys get SFMC Connect logs?

PS - some contextual info:
We are on Multi-Org with two business units connected to the same Sales Cloud org.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your connection is broken. I would login with my Connected Tracking user into the Salesforce and go to Marketing Cloud to see if that is connected. Also,do check if you are on Tenant Specific thing which is at the end of the marketing Cloud Connector configuration page.
All Apps>Marketing Cloud>Configure Marketing Cloud Connector>Adavance>Tenant Specific endpoint.
If its not toggled on, please do that.

Note: Please do it in incognito session and keep your SFMC API user credentials handy.